# ng-view not show with Route (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ng-view

I'm doing the tutorial about angularjs. Everything is fine until working with route.
I 'm search about this problem before, but it not working for me.
I'm doing exactly the code which author type but it's not working.
ng-view put in index.html

```
<html ng-app="githubViewer">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MainController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="github.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Github Viewer</h1>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when("/main", {
                templateUrl: "main.html",
                controller: "MainController"
            })
                    .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});
});})();
```

MainController.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("githubViewer");
var MainController = function(
        $scope, $interval, $location) {
    var decrementCountdown = function() {
        $scope.countdown -= 1;
        if ($scope.countdown < 1) {
            $scope.search($scope.username);
        }
    };
    var countdownInterval = null;
    var startCountdown = function() {
        countdownInterval = $interval(decrementCountdown, 1000, 5, $scope.countdown);
    };
    $scope.search = function(username) {
        if (countdownInterval) {
            $interval.cancel(countdownInterval);
            $scope.countdown = null;
        }
    };
    $scope.username = "angular";
    $scope.countdown = 5;
    startCountdown();
};
app.controller("MainController", MainController);})();
```

---

main.html

> ```
> <div>
> {{countdown}}
>     {{username}}
>     <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
>         <input type="search" required placeholder="usẻname to ind" ng-model="username" />
>         <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)">
>     </form>
> ```

github.js

```
(function() {

var github = function($http) {

var getUser = function(username){
  return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
           .then(function(response){
               return response.data;
   });
};

    var getRepos = function(user){
      return $http.get(user.repos_url)  
              .then(function(response){
                  return response.data;
      });
    };

    return{
        getUser : getUser,
        getRepos: getRepos
    };
};

var module = angular.module("githubViewer");
module.factory("github", github);})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code:

```
var MainController = function($scope, $interval, , $location) {
                   // unnecessary comma here ----^
```

Remove comma (or insert missing parameter) and your app should start working.

In general I recommend to keep developer console open all the time during coding.

Comment: This is my mistake when i'm paste this code into there. In my source , it' correctly. I think it' problem about Route i'm using.

Comment: Yes. In MainController.js ,if i put [] like this : var app = angular.module("githubViewer",[]); it' no error but ng-view not showing. If i delete [] like this(exactly what author type) : var app = angular.module("githubViewer"); it' error and linking to this : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20$templateRequest%20%3C-%20$route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective

Comment: What is `$templateRequest`? Are you sure you are showing all the code?

Comment: Only 1 file github ( i updated in post ), make service to get data. But i think this not relative about problem. And $templateRequest, i don't know what is it, too.

Comment: You code seems fine then http://plnkr.co/edit/2PAMkqkfrJ1o6rx3e8Jw?p=preview Compare to yours.

Comment: thanks. But i see, it' seem exactly my code, but my code can't working. T_T

Comment: Template provider error maybe implies that there is something with template, maybe wrong path?

Comment: I see. It's different version of Angular. I'm using newest version, but when i change to version 1.2.5 it' working.

Comment: Yes, I googled it and seems that you should update Angular version.